# How to perform this query in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

Consider this brief snippet:

```
var candidateWords = GetScrabblePossibilities(letters);
var possibleWords = new List<String>();

foreach (var word in candidateWords)
{
    if (word.Length == pattern.Length)
    {
        bool goodMatch = true;
        for (int i=0; i < pattern.Length && goodMatch; i++)
        {
            var c = pattern[i];
            if (c!='_' && word[i]!=c)
                goodMatch = false;
        }
        if (goodMatch)
            possibleWords.Add(word);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to express this cleanly using LINQ?
What is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A straightforward translation would be to overlay each candidate-word over the pattern-word using the [`Zip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx) operator.

```
var possibleWords = from word in candidateWords
                    where word.Length == pattern.Length
                       && word.Zip(pattern, (wc, pc) => pc == '_' || wc == pc)
                              .All(match => match)
                    select word;
```

If you really want to focus on the indices, you can use the [`Range`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range.aspx) operator:

```
var possibleWords = from word in candidateWords
                    where word.Length == pattern.Length
                       && Enumerable.Range(0, word.Length)
                                    .All(i => pattern[i] == '_' 
                                           || pattern[i] == word[i])
                    select word;
```

EDIT:

As David Neale points out, the `Zip` operator is not available before .NET 4.0. It's [trivial](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/07/zip-me-up.aspx) to implement it yourself, however.

Comment: `.All()` returns a boolean, he needs a list.

Comment: @Paul: It's part of a `where` clause. To materialize the query into a list, just call `ToList()`.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing this w/o Zip:

```
var possibleWords = candidateWords.Where(w => w.Length == pattern.Length && 
                                         word.Select((c, i) => pattern[i] == '_' || 
                                                               pattern[i] == c)
                                             .All(b => b))
                                  .ToList();
```